# ansible-playbook trying to print debug strings without success

Tags: ansible

I try to run an ansible task within a playbook which should print out simple messages using the debug-module. This is my playbook configuration:

```
 ---
  2
  3 - name: s3 handller
  4   connection: local
  5   gather_facts: false
  6   hosts: localhost
  7   tasks:
  8
  9     - name: Display the config
 10         - debug:
 11           msg: "Hello you"
 12
 13     - name: Display env vars
 14        -  debug:
 15           msg:"{{ lookup('env','HOME') }} is an environment variable"
 16
```

On startup I get the following error message:

```
ansible-playbook create_s3.yml
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed here

The error appears to have been in '/home/user/create_s3.yml': line 10, column 16, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    - name: Display the config
        - debug:
               ^ here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you label your task, the hyphen in front of the module name ( `- debug:` ) is not allowed. You can see it in the fifth example at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html

The error message

> mapping values are not allowed here

indicates that no other list item is allowed under `- name:`

So you can fix this with the following adaption:

```
 9     - name: Display the config
10       debug:
11         msg: "Hello you"
```

Also please note the required indentation of the `msg:` field - YAML relies on indentations and is very strict.

I hope I could help you.